# nginx returns strange binary response only on non-SSL requests (nginx/1.14.2)

Tags: nginx, debian, http

I have ported my nginx.conf to a new device and it works great, except that responses over plain HTTP return the following.

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1 -vv --output -;
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x5628a912ba30)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5628a912ba30)
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Closing connection 0
���
```

The same cannot be said for HTTPS, which works great.

```
$ ^curl https://127.0.0.1 --insecure --output -;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

This happens regardless of if a certificate is installed or not. It happens regardless of if I'm using HTTP2 or not. It never touches the FPM. A default installation of nginx, for whatever reason, is spewing binary on plain HTTP and only plain HTTP.

Comment: Are http and https configuration the same? As you mention FPM, i assume you got some PHP files? Looks like for http the file handler is non existent or improperly setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nginx** does not support the [HTTP Upgrade mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.2), which allows to share the same port unencrypted port between `HTTP/1.1` and `HTTP/2`. Only ALPN is supported for encrypted connections (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297211/11748454)).

The selection between `HTTP/1.1` and `HTTP/2` is done per IP address-port pair. Therefore if **any** of your port `80` virtual servers specify `http2` in the `listen` directive, **all** of them will use `HTTP/2`. Arguably a **warning** should be sent to the log file, which is not the case.

Since `HTTP/2` is a binary protocol, you get the `HTTP/2` equivalent of `400 Bad Request` unless you instruct **curl** to use the `HTTP/2` directly (no `HTTP/1.1 -> HTTP/2` upgrade):

```
curl --http2-prior-knowledge http://127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on what was happening here. I was very confused why they didn't just say "don't use http2 on non-SSL ports, dummy".

Comment: There is some sort of warning in the documentation of the [listen](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive. However I believe it could be better rephrased. Also an `emerg` level log message should be issued if you have a mixed configuration of `http2` and no `http2` on the same port (unless `ssl` is also specified).

Answer (score 2):

In my instance, I had `http2` on the `:80` and `:8080` port. If you are experiencing this issue, ensure that all non-SSL enabled ports do not have the `http2` option on as well, then do a hard restart of the service. I believe if any non-SSL port is http2, all fo them try to be.